# Ajax call in AngularJS not getting data from JSON file

Tags: html, angularjs

my todo.json file:

```
[{"action":"Buy Flowers", "done":false},
{"action":"Get Shoes", "done":false},
{"action":"Collect Tickets", "done":true},
{"action":"Call Joe", "done":false}]
```

My Script:

```
 var model = {user: "Adam"};
    var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp",[]);
    todoApp.run(function($http){
        $http.get("todo.json").success(function(data){
            model.items = data;
        });
    });
```

When I open developer console in Edge I am getting the following error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'success' todo.html (11,12)
```

My JSON, HTML/Script file are all in the same directory.

Comment: Probably related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6  But that's not exactly clear, since you haven't mentioned the version of angular in use here.

Comment: AngularJS v1.6.9

Comment: so then definitely the article I linked (and was marked as duplicate) is the correct answer.